# Daemonize cherrypy server for django

Tags: django, cherrypy

I am using the CherryPy server for deploying Django.Specifically I am using the instructions [here](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/25/serving-django-cherrypy/). This conveniently packages the Cherrypy server within the Django manage.py command and provides the following options:

```
root@appportal /home/Protrak# ./manage.py runcpserver help

Run this project in a CherryPy webserver. To do this, CherryPy from
http://www.cherrypy.org/ is required.

 runcpserver [options] [cpserver settings] [stop]

Optional CherryPy server settings: (setting=value)
host=HOSTNAME         hostname to listen on
                      Defaults to localhost
port=PORTNUM          port to listen on
                      Defaults to 8088
server_name=STRING    CherryPy's SERVER_NAME environ entry
                      Defaults to localhost
daemonize=BOOL        whether to detach from terminal
                      Defaults to False
pidfile=FILE          write the spawned process-id to this file
workdir=DIRECTORY     change to this directory when daemonizing
threads=NUMBER        Number of threads for server to use
ssl_certificate=FILE  SSL certificate file
ssl_private_key=FILE  SSL private key file
server_user=STRING    user to run daemonized process
                      Defaults to www-data
server_group=STRING   group to daemonized process
                      Defaults to www-data

Examples:
  Run a "standard" CherryPy server server
  $ manage.py runcpserver

  Run a CherryPy server on port 80
  $ manage.py runcpserver port=80

  Run a CherryPy server as a daemon and write the spawned PID in a file
  $ manage.py runcpserver daemonize=true pidfile=/var/run/django-cpserver.pid
```

I run this server as follows:

```
root@appportal /home/Protrak# ./manage.py runcpserver host=0.0.0.0
```

and it works perfectly fine.However i then try to daemonize it as follows:

```
root@appportal /home/Protrak# ./manage.py runcpserver host=0.0.0.0 daemonize=True
```

and it just disconnects from the terminal but no background process is spawned.I can neither access the site nor do I see it as a process on the server.What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error related on the PYTHONPATH when the daemon process gets created.

Modify the code of the plugin (the one that you downloaded), add the log parameters (`out_log`, `err_log`) to the daemonizer call on the line `202` and `204` of `django_cpserver/management/commands/runcpserver.py`, It's using the [django function become_daemon](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/daemonize.py#L9).

This will help you to debug the error.